# How to use BETWEEN for datetime stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, date, stored-procedures

I am creating a stored procedure for searching. `DateOrdered` is column name in table of `datetime` type.

The problem is that I want to perform search on this column. The user can search on start date and end date. Also user can send null for any parameter, like start date or end date.

When the user will not send the start date or end date, I shall search on another option. My problem is that how can I handle this below is the query I tried, but without success

```
SELECT  
    @C_Order_ID = C_Order_ID 
FROM 
    C_Order  COrder
WHERE  
    (@AD_Org_ID IS NULL OR 
     COrder.AD_Org_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM fnSplitter(@AD_Org_ID)))  
    AND (@AD_Client_ID IS NULL OR 
         @AD_Client_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM fnSplitter(@AD_Client_ID)))  
    AND (@IsActive IS NULL OR COrder.IsActive = @IsActive) 
    AND (@startDate IS NULL OR 
         COrder.DateOrdered = @startDate BETWEEN @EndDate IS NULL 
          OR COrder.DateOrdered = @EndDate)
```

Thanks for your reply .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try like this:

```
COrder.DateOrdered BETWEEN  @startDate AND @EndDate
```

So your query would be like

```
SELECT  @C_Order_ID= C_Order_ID FROM C_Order  COrder
WHERE  
     (@AD_Org_ID IS NULL OR COrder.AD_Org_ID IN (Select ID From fnSplitter(@AD_Org_ID)))  
 AND (@AD_Client_ID IS NULL OR @AD_Client_ID IN (Select ID From fnSplitter(@AD_Client_ID)))  
 AND (@IsActive IS NULL OR COrder.IsActive = @IsActive) 
 AND (@startDate IS NULL OR COrder.DateOrdered BETWEEN  isnull(@startDate,'') AND  isnull(@EndDate,''))
```

or better

```
SELECT  @C_Order_ID= C_Order_ID FROM C_Order  COrder
    WHERE  
         (@AD_Org_ID IS NULL OR COrder.AD_Org_ID IN (Select ID From fnSplitter(@AD_Org_ID)))  
     AND (@AD_Client_ID IS NULL OR @AD_Client_ID IN (Select ID From fnSplitter(@AD_Client_ID)))  
     AND (@IsActive IS NULL OR COrder.IsActive = @IsActive) 
     AND (CAST(@startDate AS DATE)  IS NULL OR (CAST(@startDate AS DATE) IS NULL OR CAST(COrder.DateOrdered AS DATE)  >=CAST(@startDate AS DATE))
    AND (CAST(@endDate AS DATE)  IS NULL OR CAST(COrder.DateOrdered AS DATE) <=CAST(@endDate AS DATE))
```

Comment: @R.T. if user will send send null value then

Comment: @A.Goutam:- Updated my answer to handle that!

Comment: but my field is of type datetime, and i want only for not  for datetime

Comment: @A.Goutam:- Updated with the better version to handle that. Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Thanks , but how i handle for datetime to date only

Comment: because in my db the data will be like 12-01-2014 10:12:0000 like this but i want to search only on 12-01-2014

Comment: @A.Goutam:- Cast it to date like CAST(@endDate AS DATE). Updated my answer as well!

Comment: GarethD mentioned in his answer `AND (@EndDate IS NULL OR COrder.DateOrdered < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @EndDate))`

Comment: @A.Goutam:- That is one more option you can go with!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  @C_Order_ID= C_Order_ID FROM C_Order  COrder
WHERE  
 (@AD_Org_ID IS NULL OR COrder.AD_Org_ID IN (Select ID From fnSplitter(@AD_Org_ID)))  
 AND (@AD_Client_ID IS NULL OR @AD_Client_ID IN (Select ID From fnSplitter(@AD_Client_ID)))  
 AND (@IsActive IS NULL OR COrder.IsActive = @IsActive) 
 AND (@startDate IS NULL OR COrder.DateOrdered BETWEEN @startDate AND @EndDate
OR COrder.DateOrdered = @EndDate)
```

Comment: if user will send send null value then how this will handle

Answer (score 0):

[Aaron Bertrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61305/aaron-bertrand) has written a good article about using BETWEEN with date ranges - [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common), this is worth a read. Also it looks like you are passing a comma separated list in a string, then splitting it with a function `fnsplitter`, you may want to consider using [table-valued paramters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

However, to actually answer your question you can use the above idea of not using between and change your query to:

```
AND (@startDate IS NULL OR COrder.DateOrdered >= @startDate)
AND (@EndDate IS NULL OR COrder.DateOrdered <= @EndDate)
```

So you have 4 permutations.

1. Both @StartDate and @EndDate are null - returns all dates
2. @StartDate is not null and @EndDate is null - returns all dates after @StartDate
3. @StartDate is null and @EndDate is not null - returns all dates before @EndDate
4. Both @StartDate and @EndDate are not null - returns all dates between @StartDate and @EndDate

Based on your comments on another answer, it sounds like you may be passing a date as the @EndDate parameter, e.g. `2014-08-28`, but still want to include all records on that date, even if they have a time associated, e.g. `2014-08-28 12:00`, this is exactly why BETWEEN is not used for date ranges, instead you need to use the less than operator and add 1 day to your End date:

```
AND (@startDate IS NULL OR COrder.DateOrdered >= @startDate)
AND (@EndDate IS NULL OR COrder.DateOrdered < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @EndDate))
```